# css columns responsive design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have div elements with all with specified unknowen heights.
Now I want to create an responsive design by putting them in 1<=n<=4 rows.

```
<div id="timeline">
     <div class="entry" style="height: (any height e.g. 222px)">
         <div class="background"></div>
         <div class="image"></div>
         <div class="entrytext">sometext</div>
     </div>
     <div class="entry" style="height: (any height e.g. 174px)">
         <div class="background"></div>
         <div class="image"></div>
         <div class="entrytext">sometext</div>
     </div>
     .
     .
     .
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/usasVideos/mhkdywvk/)

---

I tried:

```
.entry { display: inline-block }
```

problem: too much unused space because of the heights that not the same

```
.entry { float: left }
```

problem: same problem as by display:inline-block

```
#timeline { column-count: n (e.g 3) }
```

problem sorting from top to bottom not from left to right

---

### How can I sort them from left to right in a horizantal order?

---

1 row:

```
1
2
3
.
.
```

---

2 rows:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
.
.
```

---

3 rows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
.
.
.
```

---

4 rows:

```
01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08
09 10 11 12
.
.
```

Comment: Please give some sample html and css, so that we can see a bit better what you're doing. Also, I am not sure what you expect to happen if the heights are different.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what the problem is. If you want the elements to align nicely you can use JS to assign the height of the highest div to them all. I did a tutorial about this here: https://youtu.be/_uqhQf7X5o4

Comment: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/usasVideos/mhkdywvk/) or above...

hope that helps

Comment: I do NOT want to them to have the same hight but to sort them like a 2 row timeline like facebook/google+ have it, the best solution would be without js...

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to pinpoint without any markup, but can you try using Flexbox? Flexbox will ensure they maintain the same height, and flow correctly. Something along the lines of the following:

```
.container { // #timeline in your case yes?
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.entry {
    width: 100%; // Shouldn't actually need this declaration

    @from 2 { // Replace with your breakpoint
        width: calc(100% / 2);
    }

    @from 3 { // Replace with your breakpoint
        width: calc(100% / 3);
    }

    @from 4 { // Replace with your breakpoint
        width: calc(100% / 4);
    }
}
```

You'll need to use prefixed versions (or Autoprefixer), and the correct media queries.